# zeppelin: New install, no home page

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I've just downloaded Zeppelin, started the server, and loaded localhost:8080 into Chrome, but my startup page is blank.   I've attached the blank screen and what I think I should be seeing below.  Obviously I need some more configuration, but don't know where to start.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Could you share your zeppelin version? i guess it's 0.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core issue with this problem was to make sure Spark was properly installed.  You can verify this by issuing spark-shell command in a terminal and get no exceptions.
The main problem was my JAVA-HOME environment variable was set to java version 1.7 instead of 1.8.